# Object to shoot a projectile

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to make my tanks shoot, and I did all the code I think I should have done but I don't know why the tanks aren't shooting anything.

```
import pygame, assetloader
from pygame.locals import *
import random, time, math
import pygame


GRAD = math.pi/180
blue = (0, 0, 255)

wallRects = []

bullets = []

maze = [[] for i in range(25)] 





assetloader.set_asset_path("assets/")
```

I defined the Bullet Class here:

```
def calculate_dir_with_angle(angle):
        direction = [0, 0]
        if (angle > 0 and angle < 180) or (angle > -360 and angle < -180):
            direction[0] = -1
        elif (angle > -180 and angle < 0) or (angle > 180 and angle < 360):
            direction[0] = 1
        elif (angle > -90 and angle < 90) or (angle > 270 and anlge < 360):
            direction[1] = -1
        elif (angle > 90 and angle < 270) or (angle > -270 and angle < -90):
            direction[1] = 1
        return direction


class Bullet:
    def __init__(self, pos, r, angle):
        self.x = pos[0]
        self.y = pos[1]
        self.r = r
        self.counter = 50
        direction = calculate_dir_with_angle(angle)
        self.vel = [direction[0] * 2, direction[1] * 2]

    def draw(self, screen):
        self.x = int(self.x)
        self.y = int(self.y)
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, (25, 25, 25), (self.x, self.y), (self.r))


    def move(self):
        self.x += self.vel[0]
        self.y += self.vel[1]



        self.rect = pygame.Rect(self.x-self.r, self.y - self.r, 2 * self.r, 2 * self.r)
        for wr in wallRects:
            if self.rect.centery >= wr.top and self.rect.centery <= wr.bottom:
                if self.rect.left <= wr.right and self.rect.left > wr.left:
                    self.vel[0] = -self.vel[0]
                    self.x = wr.right + self.r + 1
                    self.rect.x = wr.right + 1
                elif self.rect.right >= wr.left and self.rect.right < wr.right:
                    self.vel[0] = -self.vel[0]
                    self.x = wr.left + self.r - 1
                    self.rect.x = wr.left - 2 * self.r - 1 
            if self.rect.centerx >= wr.left and self.rect.centerx <= wr.right:
                if self.rect.top <= wr.bottom and self.rect.top > wr.top:
                    self.vel[1] = -self.vel[1]
                    self.y = wr.bottom + self.r + 1
                    self.rect.y = wr.bottom + 1
                elif self.rect.bottom >= wr.top and self.rect.bottom < wr.bottom:
                    self.vel[1] = -self.vel[1]
                    self.y = wr.top - self.r - 1
                    self.rect.y = wr.top - 2 * self.r - 1

        if self.counter > 0:
            self.counter -= 1




    def generateRandomPosition():
        row = random.randint(1, 23)
        col = random.randint(1, 23)
        while maze[row][col-1] != 0 or maze[row][col] != 0 or maze[row][col+1] != 0:
            row = random.randint(1, 23)
            col = random.randint(1, 23)

        return row, col
```

Player 1:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, x, y, pos):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image, self.rect = assetloader.load_image("Tank.png", -1)
        self.rect.x = x
        self.rect.y = y
        self.rect.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())

        self.rows = pos[0]
        self.cols = pos[1]
        self.x = self.cols * gsize
        self.y = self.rows * gsize
        self.orig_image, self.orig_rect = assetloader.load_image("Tank.png", -1) 
        self.orig_rect.x = self.x
        self.orig_rect.y = self.y
        self.orig_gun_pos = self.orig_rect.midtop
        self.ammo = 5


    def checkCollisions(self):

            for b in bullets:
                if b.counter <= 0:
                    if b.rect.colliderect(self.orig_rect):
                        self.dead = True


    def calculate_gun_pos(self):
        self.orig_gun_pos = self.orig_rect.midtop
        new_y = self.orig_gun_pos[1] - self.orig_rect.centery
        new_x = self.orig_gun_pos[0] - self.orig_rect.centerx
        rads = self.dir * GRAD
        gun_x = (new_y * math.sin(rads)) + (new_x * math.cos(rads)) + (self.orig_rect.centerx)
        gun_y = (new_y * math.cos(rads)) - (new_x * math.sin(rads)) + (self.orig_rect.centery)
        self.gun_pos = (gun_x, gun_y)

    def shoot(self):
        if self.ammo > 0:
            self.calculate_gun_pos()
            b = Bullet(self.gun_pos, 3, self.dir)
            bullets.append(b)
            self.ammo -= 1



    def draw(self, screen):
        image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, self.dir)
        screen.blit(image, self.rect)





    def update(self):
        oldCenter = self.rect.center

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = oldCenter
        screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
        keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()





        if keys[K_m]:
            p.shoot()




        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.rect.clamp_ip(screen_rect)
```

Calling the functions:

```
size = width, height = 500, 400
gsize = 25
start_x, start_y = 0, 0
bgColor = 255, 255, 255


pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)#, pygame.FULLSCREEN)
pygame.display.set_caption("Sample Sprite")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()


p = Player(width/2, height/4, (3,4))



coll_font = pygame.font.Font(None, 30)



going = True
while going:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            going = False
        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                going = False


        elif event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == K_m:
                p.shoot()

        for b in bullets:
               b.move()





    p.update()






    screen.fill(bgColor)

    p.draw(screen)







    pygame.display.flip()



pygame.quit()
```

How would I call the bullet to actually appear and fire because I have the Bullet class which gets called within the Player class in `def shoot(self)`  so does anyone have an idea why the bullets aren't appearing?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for posting code, it's a key part of any question, but it should be in the form of a [mcve]. This is too much for someone to read through and understand. Try to isolate the relevant, _specific portion_ you're having problems with and cut out the rest.

Comment: ok will edit right now

Comment: you add `Bullet` to list `bullets` and you move bullets but you don't draw bullets.

Comment: so I would put info in the list `bullets` instead of doing `def draw` inside of the class Bullets?

Comment: This similar problem occurred to me and I resolve this problem by replacing a tank image with firing tank image as soon as firing event is performed.

Comment: in main loop you need `for b in bullets: b.draw()`  - similar like you move bullets `for b in bullets: b.move()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually add bullets in this way: I pass the group that contains all sprites  and the bullet group to the player instance and add new bullets to these group in the player's `handle_event` method.

```
import pygame as pg
from pygame.math import Vector2


pg.init()
screen = pg.display.set_mode((640, 480))
screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
FONT = pg.font.Font(None, 24)
BG_COLOR = pg.Color('gray12')

BULLET_IMAGE = pg.Surface((20, 11), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(
    BULLET_IMAGE, pg.Color('aquamarine1'), [(0, 0), (20, 5), (0, 11)])
PLAYER_IMAGE = pg.Surface((50, 30), pg.SRCALPHA)
pg.draw.polygon(
    PLAYER_IMAGE, pg.Color('dodgerblue1'), [(0, 0), (50, 15), (0, 30)])


class Player(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, all_sprites, bullet_group):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = PLAYER_IMAGE
        self.orig_image = self.image  # Needed to preserve image quality.
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=(pos))
        self.pos = Vector2(pos)
        self.vel = Vector2(1, 0)
        self.angle = 0
        self.angle_speed = 0
        self.all_sprites = all_sprites
        self.bullet_group = bullet_group

    def handle_event(self, event):
        if event.type == pg.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Left button fires a bullet from cannon center with
            # current angle. Add the bullet to the bullet_group.
            if event.button == 1:
                bullet = Bullet(self.pos, self.angle)
                self.bullet_group.add(bullet)
                self.all_sprites.add(bullet)
        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:
            # Rotate self by setting the .angle_speed.
            if event.key in (pg.K_a, pg.K_LEFT):
                self.angle_speed = -3
            elif event.key in (pg.K_d, pg.K_RIGHT):
                self.angle_speed = 3
        elif event.type == pg.KEYUP:
            if event.key in (pg.K_a, pg.K_LEFT):
                self.angle_speed = 0
            elif event.key in (pg.K_d, pg.K_RIGHT):
                self.angle_speed = 0

    def update(self):
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos

        if self.angle_speed != 0:
            self.rotate()

    def rotate(self):
        # Update the angle and the velocity vector.
        self.angle += self.angle_speed
        self.vel.rotate_ip(self.angle_speed)
        # Rotate the image and get a new rect with the previous center.
        self.image = pg.transform.rotozoom(self.orig_image, -self.angle, 1)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.rect.center)


class Bullet(pg.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self, pos, angle):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pg.transform.rotate(BULLET_IMAGE, -angle)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=pos)
        # To apply an offset (40 pixels) to the start position,
        # create another vector and rotate it as well.
        offset = Vector2(40, 0).rotate(angle)
        # Add the offset vector to the position vector (the center).
        self.pos = Vector2(pos) + offset
        # Rotate the start velocity vector (9, 0) by the angle.
        self.vel = Vector2(9, 0).rotate(angle)

    def update(self):
        # Add the velocity to the pos to move the sprite.
        self.pos += self.vel
        self.rect.center = self.pos  # Update the rect as well.
        # Remove bullets outside of the screen area.
        if not screen_rect.contains(self.rect):
            self.kill()


def main():
    clock = pg.time.Clock()
    all_sprites = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Bullets will be added to this group.
    bullet_group = pg.sprite.Group()
    # Pass the bullet group to the player.
    player = Player((300, 200), all_sprites, bullet_group)
    all_sprites.add(player)

    playing = True
    while playing:
        for event in pg.event.get():
            if event.type == pg.QUIT:
                playing = False
            # Pass events to the player instance.
            player.handle_event(event)

        all_sprites.update()

        screen.fill(BG_COLOR)
        all_sprites.draw(screen)
        pg.display.update()

        clock.tick(30)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    pg.quit()
```

Comment: it's working now, but when I'm not pressing anything the tank is still moving forward, is there anyway to make is so that if you're not hitting WASD that the tank just stops?

Comment: Change `self.vel = Vector2(1, 0)` to `self.vel = Vector2(0, 0)`. I only added the automatic movement to show that it works correctly even if the center point changes.